# Ratio of Order Statistics goes to infinity?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, order-statistics

> Is there a sequence of distributions $(F_n)$ with $F_n(0)=0$ such that
>   $\frac{E[\max(X_{1,n},X_{2,n})]}{E[X_{1,n}]} \to +\infty $ as $n\to +\infty$,
>   where $X_{1,n}$ and $X_{2,n}$ are independently and identically drawn according to $F_n$?

It would be great if we can find a "natural" $F_n$ that we are familiar with.

I would like to use it to prove some result in finance field.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible since $F_n(0)=0$ implies that $X_{1,n}\geqslant0$ and $X_{2,n}\geqslant0$ almost surely hence $\max(X_{1,n},X_{2,n})\leqslant X_{1,n}+X_{2,n}$ almost surely, which implies that, for every $n$, $$\frac{E[\max(X_{1,n},X_{2,n})]}{E[X_{1,n}]} \leqslant2.$$

Comment: Thank you! I should have noticed this by myself, haha. Do we know an example in which this inequality is (approximately) tight?

Comment: If $P(X>x)=x^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>1$, then the ratio is $2-\frac {\alpha-1}{2\alpha-1}$ which you can make arbitrarily close to $2$. Similar if you consider $M_n$ instead of $M_2$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy-tailed_distribution#Subexponential_distributions

Comment: A simpler example is $X_n\sim B(1,p_n)$ and $p_n\to 0$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!! I learned a lot :)